# how to check if an iterable allows more than one pass?

Tags: python, types, iterator, python-3.x

In Python 3, how can I check whether an object is a container (rather than an iterator that may allow only one pass)?

Here's an example:

```
def renormalize(cont):
    '''
    each value from the original container is scaled by the same factor
    such that their total becomes 1.0
    '''
    total = sum(cont)
    for v in cont:
        yield v/total

list(renormalize(range(5))) # [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
list(renormalize(k for k in range(5))) # [] - a bug!
```

Obviously, when the `renormalize` function receives a generator expression, it does not work as intended. It assumes it can iterate through the container multiple times, while the generator allows only one pass through it.

Ideally, I'd like to do this:

```
def renormalize(cont):
    if not is_container(cont):
      raise ContainerExpectedException
    # ...
```

How can I implement `is_container`?

I suppose I could check if the argument is empty right as we're starting to do the second pass through it. But this approach doesn't work for more complicated functions where it's not obvious when exactly the second pass starts. Furthermore, I'd rather put the validation at the function entrance, rather than deep inside the function (and shift it around whenever the function is modified).

I can of course rewrite the `renormalize` function to work correctly with a one-pass iterator. But that require copying the input data to a container. The performance impact of copying millions of large lists "just in case they are not lists" is ridiculous.

EDIT: My original example used a `weighted_average` function:

```
def weighted_average(c):
    '''
    returns weighted average of a container c
    c contains values and weights in tuples
    weights don't need to sum up 1 (automatically renormalized)
    '''
    return sum((v * w for v, w in c)) / sum((w for v, w in c))

weighted_average([(0,1), (1,1)]) #0.5 
weighted_average([(k, 1) for k in range(2)]) #0.5
weighted_average((k, 1) for k in range(2)) #mistake
```

But it was not the best example since the version of `weighted_average` rewritten to use a single pass is arguably better anyway:

```
def weighted_average(it):
    '''
    returns weighted average of an iterator it
    it yields values and weights in tuples
    weights don't need to sum up 1 (automatically renormalized)
    '''
    total_value = 0
    total_weight = 0
    for v, w in it:
        total_value += v
        total_weight += w
    return total_value / total_weight
```

Comment: I don't see the problem with the general version, did you profile them ? And what do you mean by visual complexity ?

Comment: "where it's not obvious when exactly the second pass starts"?  What can this possibly mean?  You can use `itertools.tee()` to unconditionally guarantee that you can iterate as many times as necessary.  How can it be not obvious when you're designing the algorithms?

Comment: @LionelBarret: I agree, there's no reason not to use the general `weighted_average`. I updated the question to give a different example.

Comment: @S.Lott: I just meant that if the algorithm isn't linear, this may occur at multiple locations in the code; and it might not even be fully obvious where those locations are (e.g., if a new pass is requested when some condition is violated). Figuring that out once is bad enough; doing it whenever the algoirhtm is tweaked is really bad. Hence my preference is to do the validation at the start.

Comment: @max: You make it sound like the algorithm isn't designed by just sort of spontaneously arrives on the scene.  That's unsettling.  Can you explain why ordinary design doesn't work?

Comment: @S.Lott. I will see if I can either come up with a simple example; or alternatively come to the conclusion that a well-written algorithm that requires multiple passes will have a clear point when each new pass starts.

Comment: @max: Please do.  The `itertools.tee()` seems like it's the solution to your problem.  I also know that a loop is *usually* a very serious design issue.  So, I'm confused by our question and interested to see if there's an example of a crypto-loop that's somehow not a first-class part of the design.

Comment: @S.Lott you are right. I don't have a good example.

Comment: @max: I wrestled with the same `itertools.tee` issue trying to find a way to make it "invisible" for algorithms that require two passes through an iterable.  It was never obscure or mysterious to me, it just took some care to make sure the iterator was "tee-d" properly.  I was very curious to see how it could get **more** complex through a loop that wasn't "fully obvious".  Thanks for thinking about it instead of doing what some people do: either insist that it's a requirement (when it isnt') or saying "they're just curious."  Curiosity doesn't make a bad question good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although all iterables should subclass collections.Iterable, not all of them do, unfortunately. Here is an answer based on what interface the objects implement, instead of what they "declare".

**Short answer:**

A "container" as you call it, ie a list/tuple that can be iterated over more than once as opposed to being a generator that will be exhausted, will typically implement both `__iter__` and `__getitem__`. Hence you can do this:

```
>>> def is_container_iterable(o):
...     return hasattr(o, '__iter__') and hasattr(o, '__getitem__')
... 
>>> is_container_iterable([])
True
>>> is_container_iterable(())
True
>>> is_container_iterable({})
True
>>> is_container_iterable(range(5))
True
>>> is_container_iterable(iter([]))
False
```

**Long answer:**

However, you can make an iterable that will not be exhausted and do not support **getitem**.   For example, a function that generates prime-numbers. You could repeat the generation many times if you want, but having a function to retrieve the 1065th prime would take a lot of calculation, so you may not want to support that. :-)

So is there any more "reliable" way?

Well, all iterables will implement an `__iter__` function that will return an iterator. The iterators will have a `__next__` function. This is what is used when iterating over it. Calling `__next__` repeatedly will in the end exhaust the iterator.

So if it has a `__next__` function it is an iterator, and will be exhausted.

```
>>> def foo():
...    for x in range(5):
...        yield x
... 
>>> f = foo()
>>> f.__next__
<method-wrapper '__next__' of generator object at 0xb73c02d4>
```

Iterables that are not yet iterators will not have a `__next__` function, but will implement a `__iter__` function, that will return an iterable:

```
>>> r = range(5)
>>> r.__next__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute '__next__'
>>> ri = iter(r)
>>> ri.__next__
<method-wrapper '__next__' of range_iterator object at 0xb73bef80>
```

So you can check that the object has `__iter__` but that it does not have `__next__`.

```
>>> def is_container_iterable(o):
...     return hasattr(o, '__iter__') and not hasattr(o, '__next__')
... 
>>> is_container_iterable(())
True
>>> is_container_iterable([])
True
>>> is_container_iterable({})
True
>>> is_container_iterable(range(5))
True
>>> is_container_iterable(iter(range(5)))
False
```

Iterators also has an `__iter__` function, that will return self.

```
>>> iter(f) is f
True
>>> iter(r) is r
False
>>> iter(ri) is ri
True
```

Hence, you can do these variations of the checking:

```
>>> def is_container_iterable(o):
...     return iter(o) is not o
... 
>>> is_container_iterable([])
True
>>> is_container_iterable(())
True
>>> is_container_iterable({})
True
>>> is_container_iterable(range(5))
True
>>> is_container_iterable(iter([]))
False
```

That would fail if you implement an object that returns a broken iterator, one that does *not* return self when you call iter() on it again. But then your (or a third-party modules) code is actually doing things wrong.

It does depends on making an iterator though, and hence calling the objects `__iter__`, which in theory may have side-effects, while the above hasattr calls should not have side effects. OK, so it calls **getattribute** which could have. But you can fix that thusly:

```
>>> def is_container_iterable(o):
...     try:
...         object.__getattribute__(o, '__iter__')
...     except AttributeError:
...         return False
...     try:
...         object.__getattribute__(o, '__next__')
...     except AttributeError:
...         return True
...     return False
... 
>>> is_container_iterable([])
True
>>> is_container_iterable(())
True
>>> is_container_iterable({})
True
>>> is_container_iterable(range(5))
True
>>> is_container_iterable(iter(range(5)))
False
```

This one is reasonably safe, and should work in all cases except if the object generates `__next__` or `__iter__` dynamically on `__getattribute__` calls, but if you do that you are insane. :-)

Instinctively my preferred version would be `iter(o) is o`, but I haven't ever needed to do this, so that's not based on experience.

Comment: +1: I didn't expect there would be a way to do this if the class doesn't bother to subclass from `collections.Iterable`. (BTW, can a class meaningfully derive from both `Iterable` and `Iterator`?)

Comment: Iterable derives from Iterator, so no.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the abstract base classes defined in the `collections` module to check and see if `it` is an instance of collections.Iterator.

```
if isinstance(it, collections.Iterator):
    # handle the iterator case
```

Personally though I find your iterator friendly version of weighted average far easier to read than the multiple list comprehension / sum version.  :-)

Comment: Yes, I agree. I updated my question to show an example where it doesn't seem to be feasible to use one pass.

Comment: Nice!  Looks like there is a standard way in 3.x.

Comment: This seems to work, even for the objects such as the "virtual container" `range(5)`. Looks great!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I run `a = (x for x in [1, 2, 3])`, then `isinstance(a, collections.Iterator)`, it returns `True`, even though it should return `False` since `a` is something that can only be iterated over once.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use the abstract base class infrastructure:

```
def weighted_average(c):
    if not isinstance(c, collections.Sequence):
      raise ContainerExpectedException
```